# Fortran: Adjusting position of labels and items of a table while printing

Tags: tabs, fortran, fortran90

I am trying to create a table (using a defined tab) where the values or the items should appear just below their descriptions. For example, I have:

```
    Program Test_tab
    character, parameter :: htab = char(9)
    character(len=*), parameter :: dashline = '----------------------------------------'
    integer :: A, B, C
    integer, parameter :: N = 10

    Print*,'A',htab,'B',htab,'C'
    Print*,dashline

    A=1; B=1; C=1

    do i=1,N
       A=A+1
       B=B+2
       C=C+3

    print*,A,htab,B,htab,C
    end do



    End Program Test_tab
```

which generates as output:

```
    A   B   C
 ------------------------------------------
           2               3               4
           3               5               7
           4               7              10
           5               9              13
           6              11              16
           7              13              19
           8              15              22
           9              17              25
          10              19              28
          11              21              31
```

I want `A, B, C` labels to appear just above their representative columns and if possible the demarcation `dashline` correctly adjusted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This what the format is for

```
Print '(99(g8.0))' ,'A','B','C'

Print '(99(g8.0))' ,A,B,C
```

uses 8 characters for each item.

There is vast literature about te formats and you will find a lot even on Stack Overflow. Google "Formatted Input and Output".